# Resetting a div to load new json/ajax information?

Tags: php, jquery, html, json, ajax

Alrighty. So it's been a while since i've worked with Ajax/json/jquery/javaeverything and I cannot for the life of me remember how to "reset" a div/wipe the buffer after running a json/ajax function.

Case in point: I've got a button that is effected by ajax function, the code is below.

```
function CMA(id)
{
    $('#capture').on('click',function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:'cma.php',
        type:"POST",
        data:{sid:id,uid:uid},
        dataType:"json",
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.status == 'attack')
            {
                $('#capture').fadeOut('slow',function(){
                    $(this).html('CAPTURING').prop('disabled',true).fadeIn('slow')});   
            }
            }
    })

    });

}
```

It is directly effecting this bit of code

```
$html .="<table>
<tr>
    <th colspan='2'>Star Information</th>
</tr>
<tr><th>Star ID</th><td id='starID'></td></tr>
<tr><th>Current Owner</th><td id='owner'></td></tr>
<tr><th colspan='2'><button id='capture'>CAPTURE</button></th></tr>
</table>";
```

($html is echoed else where but that's a lenghty bit of code)
The information in the starID information will change, so does the owner information (as far as I can tell). However, the CAPTURE button will not change back. as I've said, It's been a while since i've worked with anything java, so if this is something super obvious, i apologize -- but my google foo is failing me spectacularly and my brain is running solely off mountain dew and pringles.

Comment: Reset a `div`? `$('div').html('')`. Add response to it - `$('div').html(response)`

Comment: I want to reset it to it's original, unaltered state -- IE with the table that is in the div prior to the altering from the js code @ShaunakD

Comment: Then I guess you have to store it somewhere. In some variable or hidden element.

Comment: @ShaunakD There is a way to do it, as i've done it before (I'm rebuilding a program from memory). I however do not remember how it was done.

Comment: Try using `.clone()` and store it in a `var`. Use this to reset. Or use `data-*` attributes to store original state.